# Pyinstaller executable can't run on other machines (OS X)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, packaging

I am trying to package my python script (a script that asks for user input and runs solely in the Terminal window on mac). I package the application using 'pyinstaller' and the following code:

```
pyinstaller --oneapp my_script.py
```

This creates an executable in the dist folder in my targeted folder, and I can run the executable no problem. However when I try to send this application to my coworkers, the file is not recognized as an executable and opens in text editor. Trying to run the file from terminal on another computer will provide no result either.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify only --onefile under Mac OS X, the output in dist is a UNIX executable myscript. It can be executed from a Terminal command line. Standard input and output work as normal through the Terminal window.

Have you tried executing it in terminal?

**source:** https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#building-mac-os-x-app-bundles

Comment: You might make sure that: you are using a UTF encoding in your application
also you are including all the ddl when you build the application (this could be another reason why it is running on your pc and not other people's)

Comment: I've tried all of this, the problem isn't there - the executable is not recognized on other Mac's. (Maybe because it has no extension)

Comment: May i ask on what platform you are compiling the file?